# Why radiowave cannot pass through steel mesh？

Tags: rf

I cannot understand the reason for cutting off radio waves with metal mesh.

I do not understand the theory that holes are small enough for wavelengths .

I think the wavelength is vertical to the hole, but is it related to the size of the hole in the horizontal direction?

The amplitude of the wave of the radio wave is also a story in the electromagnetic field, so I can not tell if it can be passed with the physical size of the hole or not, so I can not understand it well.

Comment: ...was this question generated by an RNN?

Comment: Welcome to EESE. However your question makes no sense. I understand all the words, but not how these are put together.

Comment: i cannot speak english well

Comment: I swear I answered this same question within the past few weeks, either here, on physics.se, or on reddit, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @ThePhoton those disappearing questions - **so** annoying...

Comment: The radio waves can, if the holes are approximately a wavelength or longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can provide an easier answer, though I suppose it will just make you ask more of them.

In a metal, you can imagine that there is a veritable ocean of freely mobile (so-called conduction band) electrons available in the metal. (It's why it conducts so well.) Simplified, you can almost imagine these as a gas, in fact.

In a conductive mesh (or a microwave oven with holes perforating a conductive sheet), the electrons respond almost immediately to the oscillations that occur when an EM wave is felt by them. They will push on each other while responding to the EM wave. The electrons themselves don't have to travel all the way around, though. All that has to happen is that they are able to adjust themselves fast enough in response to the EM wave. And that can happen at almost the speed of light in the metal. (I'm not talking about the actual drift velocity of one particular electron, but their responses amongst each other relative to the EM wave propagation.)

Note that a long-wavelength EM wave only undulates slowly at any physical point. So there is lots more time for the electrons to redistribute themselves in response to long wavelengths than for short wavelengths. So larger holes will allow short wavelengths to pass, because the electron responses in the metal to the short EM wave "signal" simply can't move rapidly enough around the hole to completely counter that EM wave. But with long enough wavelengths, they can. This is why short wavelengths can pass (at least partially.) The result is that the EM wave is reflected away rather than passing through.

Yet another way to think about it is that the electrons accelerate in response to the EM wave; their acceleration itself produces a magnetic field that joins with their electric field to produce EM radiation; and the phase is such that the transmitted wave is cancelled out. (That is, if the impinging EM wave is undulating slowly enough, of course.)

There are other effects (such as the skin effect that limits the participating electrons.) But that's the gist of it.

P.S. The above effects do NOT apply to water waves hitting a wall with a slot cut in it. There is NO similarity. So you cannot use water waves as an analog for understanding the situation with electrons and EM waves.

Comment: Thank you! I could understand!

Comment: @Sano I added a +1 to your question because it was an honest question about what's happening and an attempt to get an intuitive understanding of what's taking place. Best wishes!!

Answer (score 2):

A summary answer:

For the signal to get past the mesh, each hole in the mesh must act like a very short waveguide. But if the signal wavelength is too long, then these tiny waveguides will be "cut-off" and not able to pass the signal through to the other side. Mathematically this can be explained in terms of the boundary conditions governing the waveguides and the resulting propagating modes (or lack of modes). Qualitatively it just boils down to "EM waves can't propagate through openings much smaller than the wavelength".

Comment: long wavelength water surface wave cannot pass through narrow comb slit？

Comment: @Sano, dunno, haven't tried it.

Comment: why long wave is cut by short small waveguides?